# Byte Code/IL Code execution

Tags: runtime-analysis, java

I understand that Byte/ IL Codes are interpreted/executed by their corresponding run times.  Do those run time converts the Byte/IL codes directly to machine code which processor can execute or the intermediary codes are converted to C/C++ calls?  Similarly, for privileged actions like File IO, do the run time translates byte/IL code directly to "System Calls" or does it translate it to the Wrapper API calls provided on top of System Calls?

Comment: It depends on the system.